# Auto Copy Selected Text to Clipboard

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard, touchscreen, copy

I would ask for a script that copies selected text to the clipboard of windows touch screen to use with the dictionary app. I found scripts that will auto copy the selected text to the Window clipboard by selecting text by Left Mouse Button or double-clicking a word, but unfortunately, these scripts didn't work in windows touchscreen. I'm studying medicine, and I haven't any coding experience.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The question's closed, Id